# Deploying a Java Project on Tom Cat

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat, war

I have a java project (not a web application, no web.xml etc)
I need to deploy it as a WAR on a tomcat with init servlet. 
Can anyone help me with the steps to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any project that is to be deployed to a Java web container, despite that it does not have any web front-end i.e webservice, EJB3 project, needs to have a web.xml. Map your servlet in `web.xml` and then package the project as war file and it is as easy as dropping it to `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps`.

Comment: Yes I figured it out. Need to create the web.xml and webapps folder in the main directory.